# Jenkins test results graphically

Tags: testing, jenkins

I have a jenkins setup that runs different tests and produces an output to the console like this:

applications/app1        : test_function                  : success

applications/app2        : test_function                   : fail

What i need jenkins to do is to somehow parse this information and plot it on a graph like this with the number of passes and fails.
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/60915759/lint-trend.png

Is there is clever way to do this with a plugin or do i need to create a script that parses this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use some testing framework?

Comment: its not fair to expect jenkins to provide you script to parse your test results .kindly use any of the Test framework as mentioned by glutton.or convert your results to junit format which can be latched to junit plugin easily